# Trying to make a div scrolls its content inside of a div with max-height:(px);But whenever i set the height in percentage the scroll does not work?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="max-height:450px; overflow: auto;">
                    <table  id="improvementTbl" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped nowrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody class="scrollit">
                            <tr ng-repeat="data in roceImprovementList" ng-style="{'font-weight': ($first?'bold':'')}">
                                <td  width="9%"  class="tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.particulars}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.particulars}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%"  class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.calcBud}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.CALC_BUDGET}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.perSaleBud}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.PERC_TO_SALE_BUDGET}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.actMovPer}}" data-placement="bottom" onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.ACTUAL_MOVEMNT_PERC_BUDGET}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.calcAct}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.CALC_ACTUAL}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.saleAct}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.PERC_TO_SALE_ACTUAL}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.actMov}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.MOVEMENT_ACTUAL}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.roceMov}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.ROCE_MOVEMENT}}</td>
                                <td  width="9%" class="table-text-right tooltip-enable-mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#bridgeChartPopup"  title="{{data.roce}}" data-placement="bottom"  onmouseenter="tooltipEnterEvent($(this))" onmouseleave="tooltipLeaveEvent($(this))">{{data.ROCE}}</td>
                                <td   ng-show="showColumn?true:isSingleUnitCompany?true:false" ><input placeholder="Enter comments here..." style="width: 100%; padding:3px;" id="commentTextImprovement" ng-change="inputComment(data, 'commentTextImprovement', $index)" ng-model="values[$index]" type="text"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-if="redReportList.length==0">
                                <td colspan="8" class="text-center">No record found.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your program [does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: Learn [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To set a percentage height, its parent element(*) must have an explicit height.
Alternatively, all modern browsers and IE>=9 support new CSS units relative to viewport height (vh) and viewport width (vw), for example:

```
.div{
height: 90vh;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```